# How can I custom data table plugin of jquery ajax request?

Tags: jquery, datatables

We can use datatable plugin request data from server like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
} );
```

We write the server url as "sAjaxSource": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php".
but if I want custom the request just ues a asynchronous function just like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "requestFunction": function(params, callback){
          callback([....]);
     }
} );
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using: `fnServerData`

This parameter allows you to override the default function which obtains the data from the server (`$.getJSON`) so something more suitable for your application. For example you could use POST data, or pull information from a Gears or AIR database.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "xhr.php",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
      oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
        "dataType": 'json',
        "type": "POST",
        "url": sSource,
        "data": aoData,
        "success": fnCallback
      } );
    }
  } );
} );
```

Comment: thanks! And why write "oSettings.jqXHR = ..."? I remove "oSettings.jqXHR = " and then it still work well